# Recurring 'Broadcast Message' in terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, mojave

Yesterday I updated my Macbook Air (early 2015) to macOS Mojave.

Since then when I open a terminal window I am getting recurring messages. I can't run any terminal command at the moment.

What can cause this message?

[image]

Comment: can you stop it with control + C

Comment: No, it does stop it for a little while. Then it starts again.

Comment: What do you mean by that? I am an admin user, is that different?

Comment: Thanks. But it's a bit strange. I can't see the option Join or Edit in the preferences screen. See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnZ85.png. Are the instructions on the Apple site old?

Comment: Oh I didn't look well, it was a language issue. The Dutch words are a bit different. This helped as well. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mA3CuWQ56_4.  But Root user is turned off at the moment. Is there a proces I should end in rootmode?

Comment: see my answer ...

Answer (score -1):

Your system is running something called the Malloc Debugging and reporting a problem in your memory ? It is a program to detect memory bugs. Since it is stuck in a endless loop, the reported memory bug might not even exist.

It reports the same bug in your memory, over and over as seen here.

[image]

More info about Debugging memory-related bugs

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MallocDebug.html

To stop the program in Terminal try Use key combination in Terminal Ctrl + C. or, Ctrl + Z , or CTRL+ \

You can also try...

Simple test is to start in Safe mode, or even more simple is to create new user account and try it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't think there is a problem with my memory (I did a diagnostic with hitting D while starting my laptop). Some googling tells me that apps or processes can give errors, like this. I think this is coming from 'mms'. Activity monitor says `mms` is part of `launchd`. I am guessing  that a program running in the background is causing this. But I am not sure which one.

Comment: mms is just message format (Multimedia Messaging Service (MMS) is a standard way to send messages, and that mms it is actually telling you that the program called `Malloc` is reporting a bug in your memory. The standard hardware test with D does not do in depth RAM test. The `Malloc` program is stuck in a loop and not responding. Did you manage to shut it down as per my instructions.